# Lipschitz and Hölder continuous measures

Tags: measure-theory

There are many notions and definitions that we have for functions which are transfered over to measures. For example, absolute continuity or the Fourier transform. Regular distributions are generalized to distributions generated by a measure and so on. But when I google "Lipschitz continuous measure", I don't find anything. I would define Lipschitz continuity of a measure $\mu$ with respect to another measure $\nu$ (both defined on a sigma algebra $\Sigma$) by the existence of a constant $C > 0$ such that $\mu(\Delta)\le C\nu(\Delta)$ for all $\Delta\in\Sigma$. Similarly, Hölder continuity: $\mu(\Delta)\le C\nu(\Delta)^\alpha$ for all $\Delta\in\Sigma$. Well, it is not hard to see that $\alpha$-Hölder continuity is equivalent to the density function $d\mu/d\nu$ being weak $L^p$ w.r.t. $\nu$, where $p = (1-\alpha)^{-1}$, and this might be it. But maybe not...

My question is whether anybody has seen anything like this before. I have Lipschitz continuity of a measure w.r.t. Lebesgue measure as a characterization of a certain property and would like to know whether this relationship of measures has been considered somewhere some time.

Comment: I would call it "a measure of bounded density", which is indeed [a term in use](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5526)

Comment: Wow. I did not expect someone to comment or answer my question after three weeks. Thank you, @404.